# CURL error (58) : SSL: Can't find the certificate “…” and its private key using PKCS#12 on MacOSX

Tags: macos, curl, pkcs#12

I've built Curl on OSX against Secure Transport as follows :

`./configure --with-darwinssl`

Now I am trying to connect to a website using a PKCS#12 certificate file as follows :

`/usr/local/bin/curl --cert /Users/mid/cert.p12 --pass password https://stackoverflow.com`

However, I keep hitting the following error :

`curl: (58) SSL: Can't find the certificate "/Users/mid/cert.p12" and its private key in the Keychain.`

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you execute the command from the same directory as the file and specify it as ./cert.p12 is there any change?

Comment: @PhillipMills No luck, same error even with a relative path starting with "./"

Comment: I have the same issue, I have installed curl (7.68.0) via brew and it doesn't help.

Comment: @timaschew There is an open issue here (https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4801) with a potential fix in a PR, but the thing is not getting quite the attention it requires, and the PR got closed without testing apparently

Comment: Actually I don't know if I'm using a PKCS#12 cert. How do I find it out? I'm using these files: example_client_tls.cer, example_client_tls.key from this website: https://developer.ing.com/openbanking/get-started/openbanking

Comment: I think the issue may be here: `in the Keychain`. Curl is looking in your system's keychain for a private key and certificate.